# React app not receiving cookies from Node.js app - both running on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, vercel

server.vercel.app is the backend for client.vercel.app. At login the server generates a cookie containing a jsonwebtoken.

```
const token = jwt.sign({ payload: email }, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "30m",
  });
  const serialized = cookie.serialize("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
    path: "/",
  });
  console.log("serialized:", serialized);
  res.cookie(ChatCookie, serialized);
```

Vercel uses HTTPS. If I run both client and server on LOCALHOST:, using http - all is good. I see the cookie in the browser developer tools.
Running on vercel, through logging I see the cookie is generated on the server, but I don't see the cookie in the browser.
the server also sets some headers as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin.toLowerCase();
  if (origin.includes("localhost") || origin.includes("vercel.app")) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  } else {
    console.log("setHeader", origin);
  }
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, GET, POST, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  return next();
});
```

Which are required for "credentials: 'include'" on the client, which is required to get the cookie.

Comment: The secure attribute in the cookie configuration is being set twice, Any particular reason? I think the second assignment will overwrite the first one. Also it will be helpful if you share index file of node.js with your question.

Comment: Sorry the second secure was  removed after o posted this. No effect.

Comment: share index file of node.js.